# Google Calendar, Java : Set up google event colour based on cell value

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Based on a Google Video Tutorial, I created a function to create events on a Google Calendar. It works perfectly, but Im trying to set the color of the event based on cell value.
Now Im capable of setting the Event Name, start date, end date and description, the only thing left is to set the color.

Im trying this but it doesn't work:

```
    function Planificacion() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("F5").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);



    var turnos = spreadsheet.getRange("B9:F10").getValues();




    for (x=0;x<turnos.length; x++) {
      var turno = turnos[x];

      var proyectos = turno[0];
      var comienzo = turno[1];
      var termino = turno[2];
      var instalador = turno[3];
      var especialidad = turno[4];


      eventCal.createEvent(proyectos,comienzo,termino) 
      .setDescription(instalador) 
      .setColor(if (especialidad == "HDPE") {"9"}"

    }


    }
```

where the color is set based on the value in the cell "especialidad" (which means specialty in spanish)
Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if', línea: 32, archivo: Código.gs

There are five possible options for "especialidad", based on "especialidad", the possible values for especialidad are "HDPE", "PVC", "Ferti", "Elec", "Soldador".
I dont care which color has to be set based on the "especialidad" value, for "HDPE" I chose blue ("9")

Again, the code works except the part of the color (Error)
Please help

Thanks !

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if', línea: 32, archivo: Código.gs` means that you have an error in line 32 of your code. If you want people to help you troubleshooting - please provide your full relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem comes from the line `.setColor(if (especialidad == "HDPE") {"9"}"`

Apart from a syntax error ( you opened a `(` bracket and closed it with a `"` instead of `)`, the are two deeper underlying issues.

1. If you did not define what should happen if `especialidad == "HDPE"` evaluates to false
2. You cannot immlement the `if` statement inside the method `.setColor()`

Instead you can evaluate `especialidad == "HDPE"` first and pass are result accroding to the outcome to a variable which you assign as a parameter to `.setColor()`.

Sample:

```js
...
  for (x=0;x<turnos.length; x++) {
    ...
    var color;
    if (especialidad == "HDPE") {
      color = "9";
    }else{
      color = "8";
    }
    
    eventCal.createEvent(proyectos,comienzo,termino) 
    .setDescription(instalador) 
    .setColor(color);
    }
...
```

Comment: Now, I want to set the range based on numberof cells. For example, if I jave only one entry, then the Range would be B9:F9, if it has two entries, B9:F10...
How do I do it?

Comment: Hi @Petermaster! In general, when you have a new question according to the Stackoverflow guidelines you should create a new post, but as a quick hint: to retrieve a range you can use the method [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) - which allows you to pass the number of rows or columns as a dynamic variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry  @ziganotschka Im new to this. Thanks for the approach.